# when does binding occur for Compile load and Run

Tags: wpf

I need to figure out the following:

Using keywords “compile”, “load”, and “run”, describe three different variable bindings in the table below. For each binding (a), (b) and (c), describe a situation for which this kind of binding occurs. (a situation corresponds to a variable in a particular location in a given programming language).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
xxxxxx      |  Name |   Address |   Type |  value | Lifetime |  scope |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

compile
    load
    run

Comment: In C# compile simply means the source code is turned into intermediate language.  The load phase happens when the program gets "loaded" into memory in order to be "run".  The "run" phase happens when the machine  executes the "entry point" of the program that is in memory.

Comment: To answer the question, binding doesn't happen until "after" loading the program into memory. In WPF binding happens when the InitializeComponent methods are executed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. the question actually asks when does the binding happen for Scope, Address, names, types.. etc...

Comment: The answer is still the same, it happens at InitializeComponent time. (For all three fields that are bound to the datacontext of the XAML.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the details you require, but binding occurs when InitializeComponent() is executed in the xaml file